# Angle between two edges of a graph

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math

Im trying to calculate the angle between two edges in a graph, in order to do that I transfer both edges to origin and then used dot product to calculate the angle. my problem is that for some edges like `e1` and `e2` the output of `angle(e1,e2)` is `-1.#INDOO`.
what is this output? is it an error? 
Here is my code:

```
double angle(Edge e1, Edge e2){
    Edge t1 = e1, t2 = e2;
    Point tail1 = t1.getTail(), head1 = t1.getHead();
    Point u(head1.getX() - tail1.getX(), head1.getY() - tail1.getY());

    Point tail2 = t2.getTail(), head2 = t2.getHead();
    Point v(head2.getX() - tail2.getX(), head2.getY() - tail2.getY());

    double dotProduct = u.getX()*v.getX() + u.getY()*v.getY();
    double cosAlpha = dotProduct / (e1.getLength()*e2.getLength());

    return acos(cosAlpha);
}
```

`Edge` is a class that holds two Points, and `Point` is a class that holds two double numbers as x and y.
Im using `angle(e1,e2)` to calculate the orthogonal projection length of a vector like `b` on to a vector like `a` :

```
double orthogonalProjectionLength(Edge b, Edge a){
    return (b.getLength()*sin(angle(b, a) * (PI / 180)));
}
```

and this function also sometimes gives me `-1.#INDOO`. you can see the implementation of `Point` and `Edge` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8598868/).
My input is a set S of n `Point`s in 2D space. Iv constructed all edges between p and q (p,q are in S) and then tried to calculate the angle like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < E.size(); j++){
        if (i == j)
        cerr << fixed << angle(E[i], E[j]) << endl; //E : set of all edges
    }
```

If the problem comes from `cos()` and `sin()` functions, how can I fix it? is here other libraries that calculate sin and cos in more efficient way?

look at [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8599018/) example.
the inputs in this example are two distinct points(like p and q), and there are two Edges between them (`pq` and `qp`). shouldnt the `angle(pq , qp)` always be 180 ? and `angle(pq,pq)` and `angle(qp,qp)` should be 0. my programm shows two different kinds of behavior, sometimes `angle(qp,qp) == angle(pq,pq) ==0` and `angle(pq , qp) == angle(pq , qp) == 180.0`, and sometimes the answer is `-1.#INDOO` for all four edges.
[image: Out:]

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8599320/) is a code example.
run it for several times and you will see the error.

Comment: Please show us an example.

Comment: What's that 180 for? Everything should be in radians already so just leave it in radians.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is outside the code you have posted. But it would seem that your problem is that edges have zero length, which leads to divide by zero problems. Without seeing more code it's hard to say for sure why that is.

Comment: I would print the partial results throughout the calculation (or step through in debugger and look at the results). Most likely, something ends up being calculated in a way that isn't what you expect.

Comment: check if your dot product is in `<-1,+1>` range ... due to float rounding it can be for example 1.000002045 which will cause acos to fail. so add two ifs and clamp to this range. or use faster way: `acos(0.99999*dot)` but that lowers the precision for all angles and also if 0.9999 constant is too big then the error is still present

Comment: @Spektre ,Thanks alot, Iv added two ifs and the problem is no more, I also checked it with cerr, sometimes cosTeta is greater than 1 and sometimes lower than -1. Please write your comment in an answer. there may be others with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer moved from mine comment

check if your dot product is in `<-1,+1>` range ...

- due to float rounding it can be for example 1.000002045 which will cause `acos` to fail.
- so add two `if`s and clamp to this range.
- or use faster way: `acos(0.99999*dot)`
- but that lowers the precision for all angles
- and also if `0.9999` constant is too big then the error is still present

Answer (score 3):

You want the projection and you go via all this trig? You just need to dot b with the unit vector in the direction of a. So the final answer is

```
(Xa.Xb + Ya.Yb) / square_root(Xa^2 + Ya^2)
```

Did you check that cosAlpha doesn't reach 1.000000000000000000000001? That would explain the results, and provide another reason not to go all around the houses like this.

Comment: still have to make sure  that `Xa^2 + Ya^2 != 0`

Comment: Thanks alot, but anyway I need the angle, because I also want to construct a cone with angle TETA and check weather a point is in this cone or not.

Comment: fejese is right about checking the non-zero length, but it's hard to imaging you trying to project onto a point anyway.

Comment: Your angle algorithm only returns acute angles so it'll wrongly report negative projections as positive. Even if you need the angle elsewhere, you still shouldn't involve it in this projection.

Comment: Trace out cosAlpha. If it's 1.0000000001, then the arccos is indeterminate.

Comment: Which is yet another reason to go by the direct route instead of faffing around with angles.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like dividing by zero. Make sure that your vectors always have `0<` length.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I feel that this is an answer. Not full code and everything but still. It answers what that `-1.#INDOO` error is and what causing it.

Answer (score 1):

A recommended way to compute angles is by means of the `atan2` function, taking two arguments. It returns the angle on four quadrants.

You can use it in two ways:

- compute the angles of `u` and `v` separately and subtract: `atan2(Vy, Vx) - atan2(Uy, Ux)`.
- compute the cross- and dot-products: `atan2(Ux.Vy - Uy.Vx, Ux.Uy + Vx.Vy)`.

The only case of failure is `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks alot, doing like this is easier than my way.